# Convert hostname to url

Tags: node.js, parsing, url, dns, hostname

So I have a problem that's related to converting / finding final destination based on hostname.
Are there any automated tools / npm packagets, or if you could point me in the right direction for writing my own implementation for following:
I have multiple hostnames, I would like to do the same thing browsers (Chrome in my case) do, enter only hostname and it automatically checks for http, https, and redirects me to the final for example "https://www.google.com/blahblah". I am sure this is achievable but I am not entirely sure how.
Any help is welcome :)

I tried navigating using multiple libraries in node.js (long ago in c# as well) but non of them accept hostname without http / https (and I don't want to manually try both because some old servers are accepting both).

In short: I want the same thing Chrome does when you navigate to hostname :D

Comment: Isn't that what chrome does? Tries `https` first and falls back to `http`?

Comment: I am not sure honestly, it's possible that it checks for open ports on 443 and 80, or just tries https then falls back to http.